# Idle time before rendering in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I'm investigating the reasons why my web pages are rendered so slow.

I was running it in VS .NET 4.5 on localhost.

When I use the Chrome Developer Tools to monitor the performance, I noticed the super long idle time before the page content were actually been rendered.

Screenshot of the developer tool:
[image]

As can be seen from the capture, I clicked button at 3000ms, and the files including css and js started to be processed at 8000ms, I'm wondering what is happening between 3000ms - 8000ms?

The link here [Idle time in frame rendering in Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545581/idle-time-in-frame-rendering-in-chrome-devtools) says the idle time is "the time when the browser is waiting on the CPU or GPU to do some processing", is that true? And why it's wasting so much time? I tried to use stopwatch to monitor the processing time in the controller, and that's less than 3 seconds.

Thanks in advance for any help.